# TIkZ: fit clipped nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit, path-clipping

I would like to draw a box that encloses several shapes using the `fit` option. But when some shapes are clipped, `fit` still takes the whole shape into.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-1cm, -1cm) rectangle ++(1cm, 2cm);
        \node [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (A) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
        \clip (-1cm, -1cm) rectangle ++(1cm, 2cm);
        \node [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (B) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node [draw=blue, line width=1mm, inner sep=1mm, rectangle, fit=(A) (B)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result.

[image: Fitted rectangle doesn't ignore the clipped out part.]

Is there a way to fit better my shapes?

Since those `scope` environments are generated automatically (with an `append after command` option) I'd like to keep them as similar as possible. Other than that, I'd take any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fit the `B.center`

```
\node [draw=blue, line width=1mm, inner sep=1mm, rectangle, fit=(A) (B.center)] {};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-1cm, -1cm) rectangle ++(1cm, 2cm);
        \node [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (A) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
        \clip (-1cm, -1cm) rectangle ++(1cm, 2cm);
        \node [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (B) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node [draw=blue, line width=1mm, inner sep=1mm, rectangle, fit=(A) (B.center)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! How couldn't I think about that? BTW, I think you left a `use as bounding box` option as a part of a previous test. :)

Comment: @Celelibi Yes, now corrected. :-)